# How to block a website using java program without using proxy and hosts file?

Tags: java

I am looking for a plugin or software to control the browser for following functionality.

> When user submitted request(URL) from browser that request hitting my
>   application(it is running on local PC) and it is comparing with
>   predefined list of URLs , if that requested URL is available in
>   predefined list it will block response other wise it will give normal
>   response

I am looking for a method that does not use the hosts file, or a proxy.

Comment: sounds like the wrong tool for the job, by a longshot! because java normally only works inside or rather as a virtual machine and doesn't  see outside that. and normally one uses a (web) proxy server to block sites.  It might be possible though. But how to do it in java is a programming question, for stackoverflow. should be migrated there

Comment: I don't even think the wrong tool can even be used in a case like this.  The user can simply uninstall Java which makes your program not run.

Comment: @ramhound; @barlop: I think he wants to block a website which has a (malicious, lascivious?) java program??

Comment: @horatio ah you're probably right

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution would be to block said website on an upstream network device.  This would be a router, firewall, or similar.  What you are asking doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are some pre-existing softwares to handle this. You can use that, if you are comfortable.

Rather than re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: thank you for giving replay. but i want to know how those software's working .